# Second parameter to limit fields in find() not working in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

[Mongodb Database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIxxv.png)

I want to omit the `_id` field in my result

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/",function(err,client){
    var db = client.db("customerDetails");
    db.collection("customerName").find({},{ _id : 0}).toArray(function(error,result){
        console.log(result);
        client.close();
    });
});
```

Looked up from w3 schools

But somehow its not working. I still get the `_id` field in my result object.
What am i missing ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 3.0 of the mongodb driver, the second parameter to `find()` is the options object, not the projection document. See the documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find). To send a projection document, set the `projection` property of the options document. E.g.

```
db.collection("customerName").find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } })
```

Alternatively, use the [project method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#project):

```
db.collection("customerName").find({}).project({ _id: 0 })
```

In version 2.2 of the mongodb driver, the second argument of `find` was indeed the projection document. This has changed in the latest version (3.0). So some blog posts might not be up to date. See the relevant section of the 3.0 changelog [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#find).

Answer (score 1):

In version `3.4.9` of the mongodb you can simply achieve this by:

```
db.getCollection('data').find({}, { _id: 0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Using the boolean "false".

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/",function(err,client){ var db = client.db("customerDetails"); db.collection("customerName").find({},{ _id : false}).toArray(function(error,result){ console.log(result); client.close(); }); });
```