# How Do I Print the Contents of Certain Fields from my Mongo Database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("books");
    dbo.collection("bookdetails").find({}, { title: 0 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

It is my understanding that by having `{ title: 0 }` it should be sending everything except the title to the array, so printing the array should print everything in my db except the title. When I run this code, it prints everything including the title. What am I doing wrong? How to I exclude it from printing the title? Everything I've looked up says that my code is right, but it can't be since it's not working.

Comment: code seems okay to  me. Just think that title should be inside quotes. "title": 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second parameter to limit fields in find() not working in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968455/second-parameter-to-limit-fields-in-find-not-working-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run this code, it prints everything including the title. What am I doing wrong? How to I exclude it from printing the title?

This is because you're not using `projection` and the format is different from the doc

As per [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), you need to use `projection` to specify or restrict fields to return.

> By default, queries in MongoDB return all fields in matching documents. To limit the amount of data that MongoDB sends to applications, **you can include a projection document to specify or restrict fields to return**.

Making those changes to your code,

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("books");
  dbo.collection("bookdetails").find({})
    .project({title: 0})   // projection does the restriction
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      db.close();
    });
});
```